# How to add two random variable's pdf?

Tags: random-variable

X,Y are independent random variables.
X's pdf = f(x)
Y's pdf = g(x)
if Z= X+Y
what is the Z's pdf?
Can it be calculated?

Comment: The *first hit* upon Googling the very title of this question produces a good answer: please read our faq about the wisdom of doing a little bit of research before asking a question.

Comment: @whuber but now this question is ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reference: http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter7.pdf

If $X$ and $Y$ are two independent, continuous random variables, then you can find the distribution of $Z=X+Y$ by taking the convolution of $f(x)$ and $g(y)$:$$h(z)=(f*g)(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)g(z-x)dx$$If $X$ and $Y$ are two independent, discrete random variables, then you can find the distribution of $Z=X+Y$ by taking the discrete convolution of $X$ and $Y$:$$\mbox{P}(Z=k)=\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}\mbox{P}(X=i)\cdot\mbox{P}(Y=k-i)$$

Comment: Thank you~Can I also ask if Z2=X-Y,what is the pdf of Z2? (This time I have do the search and couldn't find the answer)(Should I post another question or just here is ok?)

Comment: It's pretty much the same as what I've written above. $X-Y$ is the same as $X+(-Y)$. The distribution of $-Y$ is the same as the distribution of $Y$ except that it is mirrored over the vertical line at 0.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is the domain for $f(x)$ then $h(z)=\int_{x\in A}f(x)g(z-x)\,dx$.

A sum would be used in the discrete case.